# Storing an X.509 certificate into a keystore using java code

Tags: java, keystore, keytool

I have an X.509 certificate created using bouncycastle library. How can I store it into a java Keystore?

I tried this code

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

// get user password and file input stream
char[] password = getPassword();
java.io.FileInputStream fis =
    new java.io.FileInputStream("keyStoreName");
ks.load(fis, password);
fis.close();
```

I found this code [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html), but the key store created using this way does not work with keytool, it tells me the keystore is corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `KeyStore.setCertificateEntry(alias, cert)` and give it an alias name of your choice. Then, use `KeyStore.store(...)` to save the keystore (typically using a `FileOutputStream`).